# is this a contradiction? "stating there are an infinite number of programs but that a program cannot be infinitely long is a contradiction"

Tags: turing-machines

i saw this comment here : [David Deutsch says "number of atoms in universe is finite", but then says "number of programs of all finite lengths is infinite". Contradiction?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/163375/david-deutsch-says-number-of-atoms-in-universe-is-finite-but-then-says-numbe)

> ""stating there are an infinite number of programs but that a program
> cannot be infinitely long is a contradiction" That's not a
> contradiction. There are an infinite number of finite binary strings,
> but a finite binary string cannot be infinitely long (by definition)."

I would have thought that this is indeed a contradiction, if we take natural numbers for example, we know that there are an infinite number of arrangements numbers can make, we also know that numbers can be infinitely long because we can always do +1. so if there are an infinite number of programs possible in this scenario, we would have to assume an infinite number of additional bits to add to the end of the program, otherwise we would come to a finite number of arrangements with the number of bits present we have to play with, allowing an additional unique "program" at this point would require an additional bit to be added to the mix just like the proof by contradiction to prove that infinite numbers exist, why can't we use proof by contradiction to prove that there are infinite programs and that programs can be infinitely long?

Comment: This is not a question about computer science. It is false that "number can be infinitely long", and at any rate, this is a duplicate of the question you linked to. You're just reiterating the misunderstandings found there.

Comment: @AndrejBauer "It is false that "number can be infinitely long"" Have you ever heard of Pi? or e?

Comment: The argument was about natural numbers, not reals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [David Deutsch says "number of atoms in universe is finite", but then says "number of programs of all finite lengths is infinite". Contradiction?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/163375/david-deutsch-says-number-of-atoms-in-universe-is-finite-but-then-says-numbe)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a contradiction: the two numbers are unrelated.

Atoms are objects that we can observe and count in the physical world, The number of atoms in the universe is a physical property of the natural world, as described by physics.

Programs, as described in this textbook, are not physical entities; they are mathematical constructs within a mathematical model of programming. Of course we can implement programs in the real world, but the text is not about such real-world implementations, it is about a mathematical abstraction.

Therefore, the two numbers are unrelated.

The number of all programs of finite lengths is indeed infinite. Do not confuse the number of elements in a set with properties of the individual elements of that set. To see this, let's look at natural numbers. There are infinitely many natural numbers. We can construct all kinds of things based on these numbers. For example, we can construct intervals, such as

1. 1 to 3 inclusive
2. 2 to 10 inclusive
3. 5 to infinity

The intervals that go to infinity are infinite in the sense that they contain infinitely many numbers; but they have a finite description, as you can see.

Now consider the set of only the finite intervals, such as the first two examples. Each of these intervals is clearly finite; but there are infinitely many of them, so the set of finite intervals is infinite.

Programs as discussed in the text you refer to are more complicated mathematical constructs than intervals, but the same principle applies to them: if we limit ourselves to the set of finite programs (which we usually do), each of these programs is finite, but there are infinitely many different ones, so the set of them is infinite.

Comment: you say there are infinite numbers in the set 1 to 3 but that isn't true for programming because we can only have 0's or 1's, so with a finite set of 0's and 1's how do you make infinite arrangements of those 0's and 1's?

Comment: No, I don't say there are infinite numbers in the interval 1 to 3. There are three: 1, 2, and 3. In the interval 3 to infinity, there are infinitely many natural numbers: 3, 4, 5, ... What I'm sayinmg is that there are infinitely many different finite interval: 1 to 1, 1 to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4, ..., 2 to 2, 2 to 3, 2 to 4, ... etcetera.